# Find data size occupied for row by each foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored customers data in one table and another 21 table has foreign key for customer now I want to find data size for each customer in SQL Server.

One more thing: there are some other tables which have foreign keys for these 21 tables, I also want to find and add data size from those table.

How can I find TOTAL data size - any ideas?

Comment: You're likely going to want to inspect the size of the indexes, and their partitions on all of the involved tables. You can do this by querying the system tables for those objects. Start out with sys.tables, sys.indexes and sys.partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find all the table associated by a foreign key from the customer table with the SQL ISO Standard views INFORMATION_SCHEMA : TABLE_CONSTRAINTS, REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS...

Once you get all the table, you must get the object_id of all these tables.

Then you must use sys.dm_db_partition_stats and compute an agregation on the "used_page_count" of this table, and because pages are 8kb, you can do a calculus of this SUM with * 8 for Kb or / 128 for Mb

If you want the average size of each customer, divide the result by the count of customers... Due to fragmentation, the real exact amount of data size for each customer can very heavily changes with the exact same data when other data movment are executed or when some maintenance is done...

If you need more help, please post the exact name of your table, including schema name.